# How to call a gradle task in a loop

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to share a gradle build file between two gradle projects.

Project A is a multiproject build with subprojects C and D.

I have the misc.gradle containing this task:

```
task doStuff << {
    println "$project.name"
}
```

In build.gradle of project A I use `subprojects{apply from: misc.gradle}`

When I run `gradle doStuff` I get the output:

```
C
D
```

Project B is a singleproject build. In the buildfile I have a list containing ['C', 'D']. I would now like to call the doStuff task in a loop over this list, so I get the same output as in project A.

I can convert project B to a multiproject build with empty buildfiles for C and D projects, but is there another way?

Comment: Could you please put this question in a wider context? What are you trying to do, what you need?

Comment: Project A needs to create profiles in JBoss Fuse and build and deploy jars for every subproject. The code to do this is in the misc.gradle file. Project A also needs to create a zip containing all the jars and the misc.gradle file. Project B then needs to take this zip and deploy the prebuilt jars to JBoss Fuse and create associated profiles using the code in the supplied misc.gradle file..

Comment: Basically tasks should not be executed manually. You can write a method (`Closure`) that does it.

Comment: How would I do that? Write a method in misc.gradle that can be called both from the doStuff task and from a task in project B?

Comment: It should be more or less something like that: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/86dc28deb8461a808c28

Comment: The doStuff task is actually of type Exec and have to execute an external command. I guess I would have to do that from the groovy method instead. I might just elect to make project B a multiproject instead.

Comment: That might be good idea.